# upload file option/icon inside the HTML text box

Tags: html

I am trying to give an upload file option which will add multiple files to DB. I am able to create an upload file option separately, but I want to give that option inside the text box.

Also, it should show the uploaded file names just below the text box (for eg we can see in skype text box or WhatsApp text box).

I tried this below code.

```
<textarea rows="3" class="feedback-input" id="comment"  cols="50">
</textarea>
```

I took an example of text area but I want to do it on a text box.

I tried and did a lot of R&D on it but till now couldn't able to do it.
Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container mt-3">
    <div class="input-wrapper">
      <input id="textbox" type="text" class="text-box" />
      <input id="myInput" type="file" style="visibility:hidden" />
      <label class="icon" for="textbox">
     
        <img src="http://files.softicons.com/download/toolbar-icons/mono-general-icons-4-by-custom-icon-design/ico/upload.ico" onClick="$('#myInput').click();" />
      </label>
    </div>
    <p class="text-here"></p>
  </div>

</body>
<style>
  .input-wrapper {
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .icon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    left: 220px;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 5px;
    margin-top: -5px;
    width: 100px;
  }
  
  .icon img {
    display: block;
    width: 25px;
  }
  
  .text-box {
    padding-left: 20px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 250px;
    /*pointer-events: none;*/
  }
</style>

</html>
```

I use CSS to put Icon inside the text box then used `onclick` event to call hidden upload `input` type